# What prevents a hacker from intercepting a nonce and using it?

Tags: security

Let's say a page is shown to an authenticated user with various deletion links on it. Each link has a nonce. What's to prevent a hacker from having sniffed that connection and gotten the nonce, and then immediately using it to delete a bunch of data by spoofing the authenticated user and using the nonce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. SSL can help a bit by preventing the sniffing. What you are referring to is called Session Sidejacking

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

I have also desribed here how you can easily sidejack a 
Facebook Session:

http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/12/facebooksessionhijacking.html

LinkedIn Session:

http://www.wtfuzz.com/blogs/linkedin-ssl-cookie-vulnerability/

Comment: So nonces are kinda pointless, then. I mean, assuming a hacker is not able to sniff network traffic, any drastic functions such as delete.php would just verify that you're authenticated before carrying out that action.

Answer (score 1):

The nonce-including links were created by the server, therefore the server knows *independently* that the nonce it supplied to user Adam is X (it associates the nonce with Adam's session).

If Mallory sniffs the nonce *but cannot also highjack Adam's session*, then the server will know that such forged requests (associated with Mallory's session and his different nonce Y) are definitely invalid and reject them.

**However**, the reason for the nonce's presence is *not* the above because in practice, someone who could sniff the nonce could almost certainly highjack the session as well.

Rather, it makes the "correct" deletion link *impossible for Mallory to guess in advance*. This means that a successful attack would have to be orchestrated and executed within the time period that Adam's session is valid, which greatly reduces the attack surface from the "I can script this today and Adam might hit my mine in 10 years and it will still work" previous state of affairs.

Comment: If Mallory cannot sniff/hijack Adam's session, then a nonce adds no extra security on top of the web site checking cookies for authentication. In other words, if Mallory is not able to sniff and therefore cannot get a session cookie, she can POST delete requests all day long, it won't matter because her client does not contain Adam's session cookies and so the server will reject her requests.

Comment: My point was that in a non-secure connection where a hacker is sniffing traffic, nonces do nothing to prevent an attack on the user's account/data.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: Unfortunately for all of us, that's not correct. Such nonces are the way to defeat [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), which is what I 'm describing (although not naming) in the last paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

Encrypted connections / HTTPS?